# Insert data into table using php

Tags: php, mysql, database

My html form is like below:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="createconnection.php" method="post">

Firstname : <input type="text", name="fname"> </br>
Lastname : <input type="test" name="lname"> </br>
Age : <input type="text" name="age"></br>

<input type="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and php file:
Table name and db name all are fine.

```
<?php
// Create connection

$con=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306' ,'root','root','my_db');
echo "hi";
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO table1 (Fname, LName, Age)
VALUES
('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[age]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I tried very much but when I execute it gives nothing and no update in table.

Comment: You really should read through http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php :)

Comment: you're using `mysqli` which is good, but why not use prepared statements then?

Comment: sql-injection aside, you should use `{` `}` around each one of your `$_POST` inside the string statement for your `$sql`

Comment: is it  LName or Lname ?

Comment: Input type test I did not seen this type in html.Please review your code then after ask here

Comment: print the query using echo or print, then copy the printed query from browser and check it in mysql using phpmyadmin or any.

Comment: Is it case sensitive? Lname or lname matters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very simple working example of your code with prepared statements.

Note the interrogation signs on the query and the `bind_param`, `s` means string and `i` means integer, [**you can read more here**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

So `ssi` means we will receive 2 strings and 1 integer entry.

```
<?php
// Your database info
$db_host = '';
$db_user = '';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = '';

if (!empty($_POST))
{   
        $con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
        if ($con->connect_error)
            die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());

        $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (Fname, LName, Age) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        if (!$stmt = $con->prepare($sql))
            die('Query failed: (' . $con->errno . ') ' . $con->error);

        if (!$stmt->bind_param('ssi',$_POST['fname'],$_POST['lname'],$_POST['age']))
            die('Bind Param failed: (' . $con->errno . ') ' . $con->error);

        if (!$stmt->execute())
                die('Insert Error ' . $con->error);

        echo "Record added";
        $stmt->close();
        $con->close();
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="createconnection.php" method="post">

Firstname : <input type="text", name="fname"> </br>
Lastname : <input type="test" name="lname"> </br>
Age : <input type="text" name="age"></br>

<input type="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Just in case here is the SQL table used:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
  `Fname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `LName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Age` int(3) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: +1 for someone actually taking the time to show the prepared statement, instead of just telling them to prepare the statement.

Comment: Thanks Prix for your effort, But this redirects to creatconnection.php and gives connect_error) die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error()); $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 (Fname, LName, Age) VALUES (?,?,?)"); $stmt->bind_param('ssi',$_POST['fname'],$_POST['lname'],$_POST['age']); if (!$stmt->execute()) die('Insert Error ' . $con->error); echo "1 record added"; $stmt->close(); $con->close(); } ?>  

error in browser!

Comment: @Programming_crazy can you be more specific as of what you did to use this code and can you like copy and paste the exact error ?

Comment: @SableFoste thanks, just the fact the OP used mysqli instead of mysql_* just made me happy enough to help him out. I mean 50% or even more just go ahead with mysql_* despite all the warning and everything its so sad.

Comment: @ Prix : I changed the createconnection.php file as you mentioned and executed the html page. Table is up to date as per your instruction, error is as given in next comment which is shown in creatioconnection.php after redirection!

Comment: Error:  connect_error) die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error()); $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 (Fname, LName, Age) VALUES (?,?,?)"); $stmt->bind_param('ssi',$_POST['fname'],$_POST['lname'],$_POST['age']); if (!$stmt->execute()) die('Insert Error ' . $con->error); echo "1 record added"; $stmt->close(); $con->close(); } ?>

Comment: @Programming_crazy are you sure the file is correct and that you are accessing it like `http://yoursite.com/createconnection.php`? It looks to me that its printing out the content of the file to your browser rather then an error message

Comment: @ Prix: I am running html page, and onclick event i am calling php file! Like  <form action="createconnection.php" method="post">

Comment: @Programming_crazy make a new file called test.php with the following content `<?php echo "test";` upload it to your site then access it and tell me if it prints just `test` or `echo "test";`

Comment: @Prix: There was little error, Instead of starting with <?php  directly, I started <html> <body> <?php and same code as previous one. Now it does what I wanted; inserting into database!

Comment: @Programming_crazy great ;) don't forget to accept the answer that solved your problem

Answer (score -1):

You should modify your sql like this (variables should be concatenated)

```
$sql="INSERT INTO table1 (Fname, LName, Age) VALUES
    ('".$_POST['fname']."','".$_POST['lname']."',".$_POST['age'].")";
```

Comment: any reason for downvote??

Comment: I didn't downvote, but please edit inside the $_POST to have single quotes.

Comment: Mmmm if I had to downvote you, I would say that's because 1) youre not doing anything different than what is done at the question, 2) youre not using prepared statements which is important and very simple since he is using mysqli

Comment: @Prix concatenation is missing in the question which is causing the real error..i agree we could do bunch of things to improve but that is not the current problem.

Comment: @harrybvp he doesnt need to concatenate since he is using double quotes and not single quotes for his variable

Comment: @Prix: Where are you pointing, can you please say how to use prepared statement? I am very new to php