# Adding news as a new .txt file from form

Tags: php

```
<h1>New Post</h1>
<form method="post">
<b>Post Title</b><br />
<input type="text" name="title">
<br />
<br />

<b>Post Content</b><br />
<!-- editor -->
<? include "./js/editor/buttons.php"; ?>
<iframe id="textbox" class="editor" src="js/editor/editor.php"></iframe><br />
<input type="hidden" id="text" name="content">
<!-- /editor -->
<br /><br />

<input type="hidden" name="post_true" value="true">
<input type="submit" value="Accept">

</form>
```

So, basicly - I have a news folder where i read all the news files.
they are all written as:
[date] name.txt
for example:
[21.7.13] Welcome to our new website.txt

Another script i have will fetch the title and the date, and will do the whole printing part.
what i'm doing is an admin panel, which allows adding new files.
i will need it to auto generate today's date in a specific format ([d:m:y]) and the $_POST['title'] as the file name, and create a text file.
within the text file there will be the the content from the textbox/editor.

can anyone help me with the create file part?
the output file should do this:

create new file named [d:m:y] $_POST['title'].txt (+$_POST['content'] as file content)

many thanks to whoever tries to help.

Comment: take a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Use a database like MySQL will make your life 100x easier to create, update and retrieve the data. Here is a very simple example of how to insert the data with a form http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123481/insert-data-into-table-using-php/17123740#17123740

Comment: Prix, I know how to do it through mysql. i'm trying to stop using it and make something easier to install for me. i've done it many times using sql but i want it as .txt files :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? Haven't tested.

```
$file_name = "path/to/save/file/[" . date( 'd.m.y' ) . "] " . $_POST['title'];
$handle = fopen( $file_name, 'w' ) or die( 'Unable to open file' ); //create new file
fclose( $handle ); //close file

$file = file_get_contents( $file_name ); //open the file
$file .= $_POST['content']; //apppend $_POST['content] to file
file_put_contents( $file_name, $file ); //write the contents back to file
```

Comment: i like how it's written, very simple . but it won't work for some reason after a few tweaks.

Comment: ok second, i'm working on it. got it working for now, will update in abit

Comment: @user2617739 just be aware that you will also need to filter the `$_POST['title']` so your file names are valid. For example if it has a forward slash `/` - `This and/or That` - it will create another sub-folder. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words

Comment: that was perfect. Is there any way to make that same script work with Editing? as i'm done with adding new file, i want to edit the current one. i know how to make it show the file contents, i just need the update part instead of adding. can you please show me how

Comment: Great! Glad it worked out. I would assume you could use `file_get_contents( $file_name )` to open the file and put the contents into a text area. When it's submitted instead of appending `$file .= $_POST['content']` you would set it to it `$file = $_POST['content']`. Notice the missing period in front of the equal sign.

Comment: meh, it's abit more complicated then i thought. well, i managed to get the title into the first input as value, and the content will be included into the textbox by a GET. so both fields are being filled by the GET. problem is the updating part. couldnt get that done right.

Comment: Not really complicated at all. Especially if you got the first part to work. Basically, you need to open the file you want to edit, put the text into a text area. When the user clicks submit overwrite the text in the txt file (`$file = $_POST['content']`) with the text that is in the text area (`$_POST['content']`). The period means concatenate. So without the period, it will basically overwrite whats in the text file versus adding to it.